# Using Retrofit to query Uber API

Tags: android, retrofit, uber-api

I am trying to get products json data from https://api.uber.com/v1/products (https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-products) but I am getting the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: shaurya.uberintegration, PID: 21380
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.Listshaurya.uberintegration.ProductsResponse.products' on a null object reference
at shaurya.uberintegration.Success.onResponse(Success.java:40)
at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Here is the relevant code

RestAPI

```
public interface RestAPI {
@GET("/v1/products")
Call<ProductsResponse> load(@Header("Authorization") String authToken,
                            @Query("latitude") float latitude,
                            @Query("longitude") float longitude);
}
```

ProductsResponse

```
public class ProductsResponse {
public List<ProductsPOJO> products;
}
```

Code from the Activity

```
AccessTokenManager accessTokenManager=new AccessTokenManager(this);
    String t= accessTokenManager.getAccessToken().getToken();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.uber.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestAPI restAPI = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
    Call<ProductsResponse> call = restAPI.load(t, 28.632328f, 77.216858f);
    call.enqueue(this);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Response<ProductsResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().products.get(0).getDescription(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

}
```

Model Class

```
public class ProductsPOJO {
public String display_name;
public String description;
public ProductsPOJO()
{

}

public String getDisplay_name(){
    return display_name;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}}
```

I think it has something to do with authorization and there is some problem with my get request. Kindly point the issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: `response.body().products.get(0)` you are assuming `products` array or list is not null, and you try to `get(0)` which apparently not the case, as it looks `products` is Null, so you need to make sure its not null before using it.

Comment: @Yazan I made that toast to verify if the array is null or not, the null pointer exception verifies that it is null.I guess the problem is with the GET request. Kindly tell me how to modify the my code to get the JSON successfully.

Comment: If a response status code is 400 or above responses are returned in errorBody() instead of body().  If you have NPE on body(), I suspect that you have something in errorBody(). Debug what is inside the errorBody() and hopefully a reason is there. Or if you have body() but not products, then converter is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Added Bearer to the access token before passing it.

```
String t= "Bearer "+accessTokenManager.getAccessToken().getToken();
```

Comment: @MnemonicFlow  Most of the endpoints require user authentication I just tried it with products first. Kindly look into this issue [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589107/not-able-to-post-a-ride-request-using-uber-api). Not able to authenticate successfully.

Comment: In case you'd like to see an overview of the endpoints and the required authentification, [check out this table](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber#method-overview). I created it for the Uber wrapper for Node.js.